# Checking if 2 files exist, and what to do if only 1 exists. Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I've been struggling with this for the last hour.

I can't seem to write this basic block of code correctly.

Basically, I'm trying to check if "jpg.html" and "gif.html" exist in a given directory.

If they both exist I write `jpg_index` and `gif_index` to the file. If only "jpg.html" exists, then I only write `jpg_index` to the file, and vice versa.

If anyone can help me here, that would be amazing!

Here's what I have.

```
directory = args['directory'].replace('\\', '/')

with open(directory + 'index.html', 'w') as index:

print "Writing index file."

jpg_index = "<a href='jpg.html'>jpg</a><br />\n"
gif_index = "<a href='gif.html'>gif</a><br />\n"

if os.path.exists(directory + 'jpg.html') and os.path.exists(directory + 'gif.html'):
    index.write(jpg_index)
    index.write(gif_index)
    index.close()
elif os.path.exists(directory + 'jpg.html') and not os.path.exists(directory + 'gif.html'):
    index.write(jpg_index)
    index.close()
elif not os.path.exists(directory + 'jpg.html') and os.path.exists(directory + 'gif.html'):
    index.write(gif_index)
    index.close()
print "Complete."
```

Comment: What's `directory`, exactly?

Comment: Forgot to include it, but it's pretty much any folder I choose. Added it to my question though.

Comment: That doesn't tell us exactly what `directory` is. If it doesn't end with a slash, you will end up with paths like `usr/binjpg.html`, and you didn't mention _what_ didn't work.

Comment: Ah ok. I always add the last slash, but I'm not too sure on how to have it there if I forget. But the actual problem is, I tried the other suggested solution before coming here, but sometimes it would think "gif.html" existed, when it didn't and would write it to the index.html so I tried coming up with a more redundant solution since I can't seem to find the actual problem.

Comment: Try `os.path.join(directory, 'jpg.html')` instead of `directory + 'jpg.html'`, otherwise paths that don't indlude the path separator character won't work for the directory.

Comment: _ it would think "gif.html" existed, when it didn't_ - okay, that's your real problem! Try printing the full path name plus the `os.stat` of the file to get more info.

Comment: Thank you Tigerhawk and tdelaney! Your combined input has solved my issue. It was very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Applying some of the changes from the comments have solved my issue.

```
import os
directory = "F:/folder/"

with open(os.path.join(directory, 'index.html'), 'w') as index:
    print "Writing index file."
    jpg_index = "<a href='jpg.html'>jpg</a><br />\n"
    gif_index = "<a href='gif.html'>gif</a><br />\n"
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, 'jpg.html')):
        index.write(jpg_index)
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, 'gif.html')):
        index.write(gif_index)
print "Complete."
```